# Passing data from a viewcontroller into tableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to get the Json data to show up in a table view cell, I have no value showing up. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. My tableview is linked Correctly to my viewcontroller(both as datasource and delegate).

Note: I havent called   self.tableview.reloadData() anywhere as of now. If this is what needs to be done, Please tell me where I have to call it. I tried on viewdidload() it didnt work.

```
//json data 


if let mydata = data {
                            do{
                                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: mydata, options: .mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                             if   let articlesFromJson=myJson["account"] as! NSDictionary?{
  self.points = articlesFromJson["Points__c"] as! Double
  self.tier = articlesFromJson["Member_Tier__c"] as! String

//My destination VC is called HomeViewController
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
               if segue.identifier == "HomeViewController" {
            if let destVc = segue.destination as? HomeViewController {
               destVc.pointrs = self.points
               destVc.tiers = self.tier
            }
        }

   }

//tableview 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MemberInfoTableViewCell
                cell.points.text = String(pointrs)
        cell.tier.text = tiers
               return cell
    }
```

**UPDATE** : I just redid it, and it works. I must have missed something tiny! And The code seems to be correct. I also added a navigation controller so the segue code changed, nonetheless. It works. Thank you!

Comment: from where you getting `pointrs` value?

Comment: var pointrs: Double = 0.0 this is just a string that will hold the passed Json value from the mainVC @PraveenKumar

Comment: Did you make sure to call reloadData from the main thread in viewDidLoad?

Comment: yes I did @leandrodemarco it did not make a difference. Is my prepareforsegue method correct?

Comment: create a data class for storing the json values. call the api at whichever  view controller you want. create a singleton to retrieve the values. This is the proper way of doing.

Comment: @PraveenKumar okay, I will try that. Could that be causing this issue though? It seems unlikely. Could you explain?

Comment: @user161993 I'm just suggesting a way of assigning the values directly irrespective of passing those through segue. But I don't think this causes the issue. Check whether you set `datasource` and `delegate` of tablview and number of rows and number of sections properly.

Comment: @PraveenKumar all correct.  It also Works if my tableviewcell is on the ViewController. Only when it is in different it doesnt.

Comment: add code for how to get data from server.

Comment: @KKRocks added. Although Like I said I can retrieve the info on same VC, it isnt showing in another VC

Comment: where you assigned data to pointrs ?

Comment: var pointrs: Double = 0.0 this is just a string that will hold the passed Json value from the mainVC @KKRocks

Comment: Share your whole fetching data and tableview code

Answer (score 0):

1) Make Sure your variable "pointrs"  is initialized
2) you do not need to call table.relaod() when you are coming on the table view controller for the first time
3)make sure you have pass correct count in below delegate

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection      section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count //Array Count
}
```

Comment: I only have one row it returns 1.

Comment: try passing a hardcoded string here  cell.points.text = "some string"

Comment: It works. It also Works if my tableviewcell is on the ViewController. Only when it is in different it doesnt.

Comment: are you using .xib as cell ?

Comment: I am using .swift only

Comment: place a debug point here. " cell.points.text = String(pointrs)" and check the value of variable points or print(pointers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,, pass the values through a function to the "TableViewCellClass" you created and then , set the values of labels from there...

Comment: Tried this, no value From main Vc is getting passed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you indeed pass data into your table view controller because your table view controller looks okay. When you pass data, your code is

```
if segue.identifier == "HomeViewController" {
    if let destVc = segue.destination as? HomeViewController {
       destVc.pointrs = self.points
       destVc.tiers = self.tier
    }//Your code can ends up here
}//Your code can ends up here
```

See my comments from the code. If any of these if statements are false, you are not passing data. So first put a break point here to figure out if you are actually passing data or not.

If you are indeed passing data, put a break point in your `cellForRow` method to again make sure both your `pointrs` and `tiers` are valid with correct value